# Help with partial differentiation

Tags: partial-derivative

I posted this problem earlier today, but now I have some other questions regarding the problem.

$$F(x,y)=\begin{cases} 
      f(x,y) & (x,y)\neq (0,0) \\
      0 & (x,y)=0 
   \end{cases}$$

where $f(x,y)=\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}$

*1.) Determine if *f* is continuous in origin.*

The function f(x,y) is not continuous in origin, because it is not defined in origin.

*2.) Decide $F_1(x,y)$ and $F_2(x,y)$*.

$$F_1(x,y)=\frac{2xy(x^2+y^2)-x^2y(2x)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}=\frac{2xy^3}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$$
$$F_2(x,y)=\frac{x^2(x^2-y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2} $$

But this derivative will only apply to $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$. Do I also have to find another expression for $F_1$ and $F_2$ when $(x,y)=(0,0)$, or should that be done in task number 3 ?

*3. Determine the partial derivatives in origin and decide if $F$ is differentiable in origin.*

So I'm a bit confused. I thought about that finding the partial derivatives in origin by using

$$ F_1(0,0)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{F(0+h,0)-F(0,0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\frac{h^2*0}{h^2+0}}{h}=0 $$

$$F_2(0,0)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{F(0,0+h)-F(0,0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\frac{0^2*h}{h^2+0}}{h}=0$$

I don't know if this is right, but how do I then determine if $F$ is differentiable in origin?

Comment: I believe the first question asks if the extended function is continuous at $(0,0)$, not $f$ itself. (otherwise the question makes no sense). And the answer is yes, $F$ is continuous.

Comment: You know what? I also thought about that, and I even sent a message to my professor about it. But he said that he ment what he wrote. I then saw one of our videolectures about partial differentiation. With another example (not a piecewise-function) he said that the function was not continuous in origo, and then proceeded to make a piecewise function afterwards. I hope you understand what I meant. And thats why I wrote the the $f(x,y)$ is not continuous

Comment: Alright then. It's just strange to ask if a function is continuous at a point where it isn't even defined.

Comment: I know, I also find it strange

Comment: orig**in**: $(0, 0)$ is the **origin**, not the origo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computation of the partial derivatives at $(0,0)$ is fine (and elsewhere too). Since they are both equal to $0$, *if* $F$ was differentiable at the origin, $F'(0,0)$ would be the null function. In other words, we would have$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{F(x,y)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=0,$$which is equivalent to$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^2y}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}=0.$$But this is not true, because if $y=x>0$,$$\frac{x^2y}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}=\frac{x^3}{2\sqrt2\,x^3}=\frac1{2\sqrt2}\neq0.$$

Comment: Ohh, so it is not differentiable in origo. Are you using this equation by the way:

$$ \lim_{h,k\to (0,0)} \frac{F(a+h,b+k)-F(a,b)-h*F_1(a,b)-k*F_2(a,b)}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}$$ ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am using.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I really appreciate it! :)